# Install pyModis on Anaconda/Spyder

Tags: modis, windows, anaconda, spyder, pymodis

I need to use pyModis on Spyder (Anaconda), but I'm not able to install it.
Does anyone have a step by step or tutorial for Windows?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour]

Comment: Why can't you install it?  What have you tried, and what isn't working?  Please [edit] your question to include this information

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda, the installation should be carried out by running

```
conda install -c auto pymodis
```

in the Anaconda prompt.

You can find it by typing "Anaconda" in the search bar on Windows. Make sure to run Anaconda **as administrator**:

[image]

If you have never installed Python packages this way before, there is a [general installation guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-cloud/user-guide/howto/#use-packages).

Comment: And how can I open/run Pymodis on Spyder? 

import pymodis
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-d6afd77c62a0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pymodis

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymodis'

Comment: I am not using Spyder myself but Jupyter notebook. So I cannot tell. But I suppose that there is a problem with the path setting. You may want to read this post about setting the path for another Python module in Spyder:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729116/adding-a-module-specifically-pymorph-to-spyder-python-ide